# What is the meaning of "I empty the bag on a table"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "I empty the bag on a table" in the following sentence (Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/which-witch-is-which.3070455/ )

> Me: I have three apples in this bag - a Fuji, a Macintosh, and a Red
>   Delicious. (**I empty the bag on a table**. The apples roll around
>   randomly then stop.)
>
> You: Which apple is which?
>
> Me: The one on the right is the Macintosh, the one in the middle is
>   the Red Delicious, and the one on the left is the Fuji.

?

Does it mean "I empty the bag which is on a table"? or does it mean "I empty the bag. Then, I put the bag on the table" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I empty [the contents of] the bag on[to] a table

The contents of 'the bag' are being moved from inside the bag, onto the surface of a table.

It's not specific as to which bag is being referenced to though - it could be on the table, or you could be holding it (there may be context in a previous sentence that gives an indication as to which bag 'the bag' is referring to)

Also possible it could mean that you put the bag on a table, and proceed to empty it.

Update based on Q edit:
It's not specific as to where the bag in question is (they could be holding it, it could be on the floor, or on a table, or the boot of a car).
It is telling you where the contents of the bag went after they left the bag.
It doesn't tell you what happens to the bag afterwards either.
The bag location is not an important part of the sentence

Comment: If so, does it mean "I empty the contents of the bag which is on a table" ?

Comment: Updated to say that it's not specific about where the bag is. The Table part is telling you where the contents of the bag end up.

Comment: If so, does it mean "I empty the contents of the bag. Then I put the contents of the bag on a table" ?

Comment: It's all one action. when you empty the contents of the bag, the table is where you are putting them, so there's no need to put them on the table afterwards.